# Query what Linux/Unix distribution you're using (from the command-line)

Tags: linux, command-line, unix, linux-distributions

When using an unfamiliar Linux/BSD/Unix computer (e.g. by SSH) from the command line, **how can you tell what distribution** (and what version of that distribution) you're using?

Some options I've tried:

- `lsb_release --all`: doesn't exist on OpenSuSE 11.3; works on Debian squeeze and Ubuntu 10.10.
- `uname --all`: doesn't give distro information on SuSE and Debian; works in Ubuntu.
- `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` in you can see which distribution's servers the machine connects to for updates. Obviously, only works for Debian-based distributions. Won't work if the computer has been configured to use a custom repository server.

Unfortunately none of these seem to work across many distributions. Is there a simple command to check?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If Python 2.3 or later is installed, this will work with [many distributions](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/platform.py#l259):

```
python -c "import platform; print platform.dist()"
```

Answer (score 10):

> cat /proc/version

might do the trick.

Comment: There are many unixes that don't support the /proc pseudo-filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

There is no one magic command that works across all distributions - you will need to try a series of things to work out an answer.

Things to try include some you have done, like `lsb_release`, and others that you haven't like looking at `/etc/redhat-release`, `/etc/fedora-release`, etc.

Comment: Also `/etc/SuSE-release`.

Comment: Check `/etc/*-release` -- but there are systems with no such file(s).